# how to read RGB Data from png in j2me

Tags: java, java-me

hey i have using j2me to read an image

i want to do some process on that image like Darkenes , lightens

i already read image as an input stream

```
        InputStream iStrm = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/earth.PNG");
         ByteArrayOutputStream bStrm = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

       int ch;

  while ((ch = iStrm.read()) != -1){
    bStrm.write(ch);


    byte imageData[] = bStrm.toByteArray();
   Image im = Image.createImage(imageData, 0, imageData.length);
```

how can  i get RGB values or how can i add some values to the array of pixles
imageData[]  so it can more lightens or darkness ,

is there header data including in the input stream i had read , that cause me error when iam adding  some values to it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do the following:

```
int width = im.getWidth();
int height = im.getHeight();
int[] rgbData = new int[width*height]; // since we are working with rgba

im.getRGB(rgbData, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

// now, the data is stored in each integer as 0xAARRGGBB, 
// so high-order bits are alpha channel for each integer
```

Now, if you want to put them into three arrays, one for each channel, you could do the following:

```
int red[][] = new int[width][height];
int green[][] = new int[width][height];
int blue[][] = new int[width][height];

for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
  {
    red[i][j] = rgb[i*width + j] & 0xFF0000;
    green[i][j] = rgb[i*width + j] & 0xFF00;
    blue[i][j] = rgb[i+width + j] & 0xFF;
  }
}
```

Comment: this is incorrect, why you are multiply the array by 4. Every pixel in the image is an integer which can hold the ARGB data. the array should be in width*height size only.